# WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR, what now?

Tags: bsod

Ever since I've built my own PC with Windows 10, I've experienced issues where my PC would randomly stop responding. In every case, I've had to perform a cold reboot, because Windows would not shut down or restart when told to. In 2 cases, I was confronted with a WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR instead. I suspect that the issues may be related, so I'd like to fix my BSOD.

Apparently, WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR appears when there's a faulty hardware or buggy driver. Unfortunately, the error itself isn't very descriptive, so I don't have much information to work with.

I discovered that Windows creates a `.dmp` file whenever a BSOD occurs, and that the files are saved in `C:\Windows\Minidump`. Unfortunately, I have no idea what to do with these files. Whenever I try to open a `.dmp` file with Notepad++, I get:

> Can not open file

According to https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/315271, I should use `Dumpchk.exe`, but it doesn't seem to be installed on my PC and the only relevant-looking link has me download the Windows Driver Kit and the Debugging Tools for Windows together with Visual Studio. I'm not interested in debugging Windows or developing drivers. I just want to see what's written in the `.dmp` file, so I know which driver needs to be reinstalled/updated, or which component needs to be exchanged.

How do I open a `.dmp` file?

Comment: "Unfortunately, I have no idea what to do with these files." Use windbg on them to determine the driver causing the crash.

Comment: copy the folder **C:\Windows\Minidump** to desktop, zip and share (onedrive share link) the files

Comment: @magicandre1981. And where would I share it to? Here? How would future visitors benefit from that? I appreciate the help, but I would rather solve the problem myself.

Comment: use ondrive to share the zip. I'll post details in my later answer, here you can see what I do to analyze dumps and others can repeat this for their dumps.

Comment: @magicandre1981. I've [zipped the Minidump folder](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AgSdnW26XtijoeocSGzIFTFLXI7R2w).

Comment: I've posted what I saw with the commands you need to run

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To see more details when you get a [Bug Check 0x124: WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff557321.aspx), open the dmp in `Windbg.exe`, which is part of the `Debugging Tools for Windows`, which itself is part of the [Windows 10 SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk).

Now [setup the debug symbols in windbg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30019890/1466046), and run the `!errrec` command with the value from 2nd argument:

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR (124)
A fatal hardware error has occurred. Parameter 1 identifies the type of error
source that reported the error. Parameter 2 holds the address of the
WHEA_ERROR_RECORD structure that describes the error conditon.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000000, Machine Check Exception
Arg2: ffff8905a872c028, Address of the WHEA_ERROR_RECORD structure.
Arg3: 00000000fe000000, High order 32-bits of the MCi_STATUS value.
Arg4: 0000000000801136, Low order 32-bits of the MCi_STATUS value.

6: kd> !errrec ffff8905a872c028
===============================================================================
Common Platform Error Record @ ffff8905a872c028
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Record Id     : 01d24ff887f68558
Severity      : Fatal (1)
Length        : 928
Creator       : Microsoft
Notify Type   : Machine Check Exception
Timestamp     : 12/11/2016 10:04:07 (UTC)
Flags         : 0x00000000

===============================================================================
Section 0     : Processor Generic
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Descriptor    @ ffff8905a872c0a8
Section       @ ffff8905a872c180
Offset        : 344
Length        : 192
Flags         : 0x00000001 Primary
Severity      : Fatal

Proc. Type    : x86/x64
Instr. Set    : x64
Error Type    : Cache error
Operation     : Data Read
Flags         : 0x00
Level         : 2
CPU Version   : 0x00000000000506e3
Processor ID  : 0x0000000000000006

===============================================================================
Section 1     : x86/x64 Processor Specific
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Descriptor    @ ffff8905a872c0f0
Section       @ ffff8905a872c240
Offset        : 536
Length        : 128
Flags         : 0x00000000
Severity      : Fatal

Local APIC Id : 0x0000000000000006
CPU Id        : e3 06 05 00 00 08 10 06 - bf fb fa 7f ff fb eb bf
                00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
                00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

Proc. Info 0  @ ffff8905a872c240

===============================================================================
Section 2     : x86/x64 MCA
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Descriptor    @ ffff8905a872c138
Section       @ ffff8905a872c2c0
Offset        : 664
Length        : 264
Flags         : 0x00000000
Severity      : Fatal

Error         : DCACHEL2_DRD_ERR (Proc 6 Bank 9)
  Status      : 0xfe00000000801136
  Address     : 0x00000000b3800000
  Misc.       : 0x00000030e5000086
```

Here you can see that you have issues while reading data from L2 Cache of the CPU:

```
Error Type    : Cache error
Operation     : Data Read
Error         : DCACHEL2_DRD_ERR
```

Using `!sysinfo machineid` shows you use an older BIOS/UEFI:

```
BiosVersion = 1805
BiosReleaseDate = 05/13/2016
BaseBoardManufacturer = ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
BaseBoardProduct = Z170 PRO GAMING
```

So [update the BIOS/UEFI to Version 3016](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/Z170-PRO-GAMING/HelpDesk_Download/) because it should improve system stability.

If you still get issues, do a CPU stress test, to test if your CPU is damaged. Also make sure you don't undervolt the CPU.