# Whea_uncorrectable_error . Mindump analysis requested

Tags: bsod, crash

Have run crash dump through debugger which identifies 0x124_GenuineIntel_PROCESSOR_CACHE as the culprit. Anybody that can confirm that this is really a hardware problem, not something else causing the error? Thanks.
Link to crash dumps. No overclocking, have run diagnostics for cpu, memory, disk. No problems reported.
https://1drv.ms/f/s!Aget539abtS4lehsKzQZ9VOxvVtuzg

Answer (score 0):

Using the [!errrec command](https://superuser.com/a/1163779/174557) shows that you have a Generic L2 Cache issue (`GCACHEL2_ERR_ERR`):

```
3: kd> !errrec ffffcd87c0987028
===============================================================================
Common Platform Error Record @ ffffcd87c0987028
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Record Id     : 01d38c73a52d0c9a
Severity      : Fatal (1)
Length        : 928
Creator       : Microsoft
Notify Type   : Machine Check Exception
Timestamp     : 1/14/2018 7:11:57 (UTC)
Flags         : 0x00000000

===============================================================================
Section 0     : Processor Generic
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Descriptor    @ ffffcd87c09870a8
Section       @ ffffcd87c0987180
Offset        : 344
Length        : 192
Flags         : 0x00000001 Primary
Severity      : Fatal

Proc. Type    : x86/x64
Instr. Set    : x64
Error Type    : Cache error
Operation     : Generic
Flags         : 0x00
Level         : 2
CPU Version   : 0x00000000000406e3
Processor ID  : 0x0000000000000003

===============================================================================
Section 1     : x86/x64 Processor Specific
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Descriptor    @ ffffcd87c09870f0
Section       @ ffffcd87c0987240
Offset        : 536
Length        : 128
Flags         : 0x00000000
Severity      : Fatal

Local APIC Id : 0x0000000000000003
CPU Id        : e3 06 04 00 00 08 10 03 - ff fb fa 7f ff fb eb bf
                00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
                00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

Proc. Info 0  @ ffffcd87c0987240

===============================================================================
Section 2     : x86/x64 MCA
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Descriptor    @ ffffcd87c0987138
Section       @ ffffcd87c09872c0
Offset        : 664
Length        : 264
Flags         : 0x00000000
Severity      : Fatal

Error         : GCACHEL2_ERR_ERR (Proc 3 Bank 7)
```

Contact Microsoft support if you still have warranty for your Surface Pro 4.

Comment: Thanks. Yes that's what I figured, but because of my lack of experience with these analysis, I wanted a confirmation that this is indeed a hardware beyond any doubt and not some driver in ...disguise. BTW I am on warranty.

Comment: @ClarkKent have you contacted the support? do they conform CPU issue?

Comment: does the issue happen after the last update to fix the CPU related security issues? maybe it is a side effect

Comment: Has not happened the last few days. Can you be more specific? What update are you referring to?Thanks

Comment: Actually let me be a little more specific. The Error has not happened since the 14th of Jan.At the time I removed the Microsoft bluetooth (sculpt) mouse and use a regular usb mouse. It occured to me that this driver is the only one not build in to surface and if this is a driver issue, the mouse driver might be the culprit. In addition, the error usually appeared right after boot, that is the  time, when i reach for the mouse.So, I got suspicious. Yes Microsoft has offered a replacement, but has not given me a definite answer.

Comment: I mean the Spectre/Meltdown CPU issue that is in media. MS provided a new firmware for it: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4023489/surface-surface-pro-4-update-history

Comment: That update was installed on the 13th of Jan on my surface. I had 2 crashes a couple of hours after that update (may have even worsen the problem), after which I changed the mouse. I will probably revert back to the Bluetooth mouse, in an attempt to verify wether the mouse is causing it.

Comment: and have you got the crashes before that new firmware?

Comment: yes had crashes before and after the new firmware.

Comment: Got the error again today on a different Bank. This is most probably a CPU issue or Motherboard.

Comment: ok, talk to MS support how to send it to them for repair