# BSOD Windows 10 in certain applications

Tags: windows, windows-10, memory, 64-bit, bsod

I've been getting random BSODs during certain programs,
but all have the same error codes.
I've put the minidump here.
Anyone knows what might cause this?
I've been looking everywhere

The minidump reads this:

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.16299.91 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Loading Dump File [C:\Windows\Minidump\031918-14500-01.dmp]
Mini Kernel Dump File: Only registers and stack trace are available

Symbol search path is: srv*
Executable search path is: 
Windows 10 Kernel Version 16299 MP (6 procs) Free x64
Product: WinNt, suite: TerminalServer SingleUserTS
Built by: 16299.15.amd64fre.rs3_release.170928-1534
Machine Name:
Kernel base = 0xfffff801`65084000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0xfffff801`653e5ff0
Debug session time: Mon Mar 19 20:15:08.808 2018 (UTC + 2:00)
System Uptime: 0 days 3:38:11.530
Loading Kernel Symbols
...............................................................
................................................................
........................................................
Loading User Symbols
Loading unloaded module list
............
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

Use !analyze -v to get detailed debugging information.

BugCheck 124, {0, ffffad0114467028, b65aa000, 84000135}

*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for win32k.sys
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for win32k.sys
Probably caused by : AuthenticAMD

Followup:     MachineOwner
---------

4: kd> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR (124)
A fatal hardware error has occurred. Parameter 1 identifies the type of error
source that reported the error. Parameter 2 holds the address of the
WHEA_ERROR_RECORD structure that describes the error conditon.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000000, Machine Check Exception
Arg2: ffffad0114467028, Address of the WHEA_ERROR_RECORD structure.
Arg3: 00000000b65aa000, High order 32-bits of the MCi_STATUS value.
Arg4: 0000000084000135, Low order 32-bits of the MCi_STATUS value.

Debugging Details:
------------------


DUMP_CLASS: 1

DUMP_QUALIFIER: 400

BUILD_VERSION_STRING:  10.0.16299.125 (WinBuild.160101.0800)

SYSTEM_MANUFACTURER:  System manufacturer

SYSTEM_PRODUCT_NAME:  System Product Name

SYSTEM_SKU:  To Be Filled By O.E.M.

SYSTEM_VERSION:  System Version

BIOS_VENDOR:  American Megatrends Inc.

BIOS_VERSION:  2101   

BIOS_DATE:  06/23/2011

BASEBOARD_MANUFACTURER:  ASUSTeK Computer INC.

BASEBOARD_PRODUCT:  M4A87TD

BASEBOARD_VERSION:  Rev 1.xx

DUMP_TYPE:  2

BUGCHECK_P1: 0

BUGCHECK_P2: ffffad0114467028

BUGCHECK_P3: b65aa000

BUGCHECK_P4: 84000135

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x124_AuthenticAMD

CPU_COUNT: 6

CPU_MHZ: c8b

CPU_VENDOR:  AuthenticAMD

CPU_FAMILY: 10

CPU_MODEL: a

CPU_STEPPING: 0

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

PROCESS_NAME:  dxhr.exe

CURRENT_IRQL:  f

ANALYSIS_SESSION_HOST:  DESKTOP-HQUIN4E

ANALYSIS_SESSION_TIME:  03-19-2018 20:50:05.0016

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.16299.91 amd64fre

STACK_TEXT:  
ffffc380`a29ca678 fffff801`65040f1f : 00000000`00000124 00000000`00000000 ffffad01`14467028 00000000`b65aa000 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
ffffc380`a29ca680 fffff80e`3b4a148a : ffffad01`14467028 ffffad01`144eb180 ffffad01`144eb180 ffffad01`144eb180 : hal!HalBugCheckSystem+0xcf
ffffc380`a29ca6c0 fffff801`65304e11 : ffffad01`14467028 00000000`00000000 ffffad01`144eb180 ffffad01`144eb180 : PSHED!PshedBugCheckSystem+0xa
ffffc380`a29ca6f0 fffff801`65041460 : 00000000`00000728 00000000`00000004 ffffc380`a29cab00 00000000`00000000 : nt!WheaReportHwError+0x261
ffffc380`a29ca750 fffff801`650417c0 : 00000000`00000010 00000000`00000004 ffffc380`a29ca8f8 00000000`00000004 : hal!HalpMcaReportError+0x50
ffffc380`a29ca8a0 fffff801`650416ae : ffffad01`144eab70 00000000`00000001 ffffc380`a29cab00 00000000`00000000 : hal!HalpMceHandlerCore+0xe0
ffffc380`a29ca8f0 fffff801`65041a89 : ffffad01`144eab70 ffffc380`a29cab30 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : hal!HalpMceHandler+0xda
ffffc380`a29ca930 fffff801`651f27fb : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : hal!HalHandleMcheck+0x49
ffffc380`a29ca960 fffff801`651f256c : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KxMcheckAbort+0x7b
ffffc380`a29caaa0 00000000`005103dd : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiMcheckAbort+0x1ac
00000000`07eaf8a0 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : 0x5103dd


THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC:  88e882887fe56e19e033ccb065f96059ef746ee5

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC_OFFSET:  c1a0ee21a537d4827e66bb5633d3be5e85e41532

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD:  4f95fe8af2e6cfcf04d63a4a4c0edcdd9add15b3

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: AuthenticAMD

IMAGE_NAME:  AuthenticAMD

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  0

STACK_COMMAND:  .thread ; .cxr ; kb

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0x124_AuthenticAMD_PROCESSOR_CACHE

BUCKET_ID:  0x124_AuthenticAMD_PROCESSOR_CACHE

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  0x124_AuthenticAMD_PROCESSOR_CACHE

TARGET_TIME:  2018-03-19T18:15:08.000Z

OSBUILD:  16299

OSSERVICEPACK:  125

SERVICEPACK_NUMBER: 0

OS_REVISION: 0

SUITE_MASK:  272

PRODUCT_TYPE:  1

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 10

OSEDITION:  Windows 10 WinNt TerminalServer SingleUserTS

OS_LOCALE:  

USER_LCID:  0

OSBUILD_TIMESTAMP:  2017-12-07 23:55:32

BUILDDATESTAMP_STR:  160101.0800

BUILDLAB_STR:  WinBuild

BUILDOSVER_STR:  10.0.16299.125

ANALYSIS_SESSION_ELAPSED_TIME:  1578

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  KM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:0x124_authenticamd_processor_cache

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {b533751b-676e-7546-bcdc-24e6c40d0064}

Followup:     MachineOwner
---------

4: kd> lmvm AuthenticAMD
Browse full module list
start             end                 module name
```

It happens at the moment in two games Deus Ex Human Revolution and Binary Domain

I did a clean Windows install 2 days ago.
My specs are:

- Phenom II x6 1090t @3.2Ghz,
- ASUS M4A87TD motherboard,
- 8 GB A-DATA XPG Gaming Series RAM,
- two WD 1 TB Hard Drives.
  I checked the HDD's and they are working fine.

Comment: Why are you using an unpatched 1709 installation?  Use windbg to analyze the dump to determine the cause of the crash

Comment: The dump above is from Windbg,and i got the version from microsofts website for windows,so i dont know what i need to patch in,i was asking who knows what is wrong,since i dont know how to read the dump properly

Comment: use the [!errrec command](https://superuser.com/a/1285768/174557) to dump the data. it looks like you have Cache issues.

Comment: is there any fix? or is it hardware based and its a defective cpu?

Comment: have you used he errrec command in windbg? what does it tell you? Also Fast Startup feature of Win8/10 can cause such 124 issues.

Comment: I havent used it,my minidump got deleted from windows,and my system has not gotten the error yet,somehow i've avoided it,it just happens in games for some reason,in one of them in particular Deus Ex Human Revolution and it always does it there,since I've gotten the computer in 2011

Comment: have you stopped using fast startup or installed new windows updates? maye the last 16299.334 includes a fix for your issue