# Windows 10 BlueSscreen Error

Tags: bsod

```
Source
Windows

Summary
Shut down unexpectedly

Date
‎04-‎02-‎2018 18:54

Status
Report sent

Problem signature
Problem Event Name: BlueScreen
Code:   124
Parameter 1:    0
Parameter 2:    ffffbe80ec35a038
Parameter 3:    0
Parameter 4:    0
OS version: 10_0_16299
Service Pack:   0_0
Product:    256_1
OS Version: 10.0.16299.2.0.0.256.48
Locale ID:  16393

Extra information about the problem
Bucket ID:  0x124_AuthenticAMD_PROCESSOR_BUS_PRV
Server information: 627d4286-e403-42ef-a5bf-5e3368a05823


From EventCodeViewer : 

Log Name:      Application
Source:        Windows Error Reporting
Date:          23-04-2016 20:31:48
Event ID:      1001
Task Category: None
Level:         Information
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      DESKTOP-10IQ3S9
Description:
Fault bucket 0x124_AuthenticAMD_PROCESSOR_BUS_PRV, type 0
Event Name: BlueScreen
Response: http://wer.microsoft.com/responses/resredir.aspx?sid=10&Bucket=0x124_AuthenticAMD_PROCESSOR_BUS_PRV&State=1&ID=96030ba8-a66c-4b8c-b67d-dc500e4f3b66
Cab Id: 96030ba8-a66c-4b8c-b67d-dc500e4f3b66

Problem signature:
P1: 124
P2: 0
P3: ffffe000f7117038
P4: 0
P5: 0
P6: 10_0_10586
P7: 0_0
P8: 256_1
P9: 
P10: 

Attached files:
C:\Windows\Minidump\042316-18734-01.dmp
C:\Windows\Temp\WER-19234-0.sysdata.xml
C:\Windows\Temp\WERDCB4.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml

These files may be available here:
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\Kernel_124_80aba1efc3e37cc2e1053fb58f6adb8bfcc40_00000000_cab_0da6b433

Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report ID: b0a87591-2c5e-45cf-898f-f5d73f574dcd
Report Status: 0
Hashed bucket: 
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Windows Error Reporting" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">1001</EventID>
    <Level>4</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2016-04-23T15:01:48.918337800Z" />
    <EventRecordID>2925</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>DESKTOP-10IQ3S9</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>0x124_AuthenticAMD_PROCESSOR_BUS_PRV</Data>
    <Data>0</Data>
    <Data>BlueScreen</Data>
    <Data>http://wer.microsoft.com/responses/resredir.aspx?sid=10&amp;Bucket=0x124_AuthenticAMD_PROCESSOR_BUS_PRV&amp;State=1&amp;ID=96030ba8-a66c-4b8c-b67d-dc500e4f3b66</Data>
    <Data>96030ba8-a66c-4b8c-b67d-dc500e4f3b66</Data>
    <Data>124</Data>
    <Data>0</Data>
    <Data>ffffe000f7117038</Data>
    <Data>0</Data>
    <Data>0</Data>
    <Data>10_0_10586</Data>
    <Data>0_0</Data>
    <Data>256_1</Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>
C:\Windows\Minidump\042316-18734-01.dmp
C:\Windows\Temp\WER-19234-0.sysdata.xml
C:\Windows\Temp\WERDCB4.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml</Data>
    <Data>C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\Kernel_124_80aba1efc3e37cc2e1053fb58f6adb8bfcc40_00000000_cab_0da6b433</Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>0</Data>
    <Data>b0a87591-2c5e-45cf-898f-f5d73f574dcd</Data>
    <Data>0</Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

This is the error summary from Reliability Centre.
My pc is restarting automatically due to this error.I have got this error multiple times in a week.
I could not find any dump files in minidump folder.
Please help me to diagnose whats the cause.

My components are : Motherboard :Asus m5a78lm/usb3,CPU: amd fx 8350 , graphics card :amd Radeon r9 280x

I GOT THE BSOD AGAIN
BlueScreenViewer report.

```
020918-33906-01.dmp 09-02-2018 19:44:57     0x00000124  00000000`00000000   ffff968d`22946038   00000000`00000000   00000000`00000000   ntoskrnl.exe    ntoskrnl.exe+75eb33                 x64 ntoskrnl.exe+75eb33                 C:\Windows\Minidump\020918-33906-01.dmp 8   15  16299   262,144 09-02-2018 19:45:14 



DRIVER REPORT FROM DRIVER VIEWER OF ntsokrnl.exe which showed in bluescreen error
==================================================
Driver Name       : ntoskrnl.exe
Address           : 00000000`6048A000
End Address       : 00000000`60D60000
Size              : 0x008d6000
Load Count        : 142
Index             : 0
File Type         : Application
Description       : NT Kernel & System
Version           : 10.0.16299.214
Company           : Microsoft Corporation
Product Name      : Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
Modified Date     : 1/18/2018 3:45:55 AM
Created Date      : 2/2/2018 6:41:56 PM
Filename          : C:\Windows\system32\ntoskrnl.exe
File Attributes   : A
Service Name      : 
Service Display Name: 
Digital Signature : 
==================================================
```

!errorc command output

```
4: kd> !errrec ffff968d`22946038
===============================================================================
Common Platform Error Record @ ffff968d22946038
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Record Id     : 01d3a1b0581e6b4d
Severity      : Fatal (1)
Length        : 928
Creator       : Microsoft
Notify Type   : Machine Check Exception
Timestamp     : 2/9/2018 14:14:57 (UTC)
Flags         : 0x00000002 PreviousError

===============================================================================
Section 0     : Processor Generic
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Descriptor    @ ffff968d229460b8
Section       @ ffff968d22946190
Offset        : 344
Length        : 192
Flags         : 0x00000001 Primary
Severity      : Fatal

Proc. Type    : x86/x64
Instr. Set    : x64
Error Type    : BUS error
Operation     : Generic
Flags         : 0x00
Level         : 3
CPU Version   : 0x0000000000600f20
Processor ID  : 0x0000000000000000

===============================================================================
Section 1     : x86/x64 Processor Specific
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Descriptor    @ ffff968d22946100
Section       @ ffff968d22946250
Offset        : 536
Length        : 128
Flags         : 0x00000000
Severity      : Fatal

Local APIC Id : 0x0000000000000000
CPU Id        : 20 0f 60 00 00 08 08 00 - 0b 32 98 3e ff fb 8b 17
                00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
                00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

Proc. Info 0  @ ffff968d22946250

===============================================================================
Section 2     : x86/x64 MCA
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Descriptor    @ ffff968d22946148
Section       @ ffff968d229462d0
Offset        : 664
Length        : 264
Flags         : 0x00000000
Severity      : Fatal

Error         : BUSLG_OBS_ERR_*_NOTIMEOUT_ERR (Proc 0 Bank 4)
  Status      : 0xf2000010000b0c0f
```

Comment: AuthenticAMD_PROCESSOR_BUS_PRV so your AMD CPU has some serious issues. look for a newer BIOS update. this can sometimes fix it, if you already have it run a cpu stress test tool and look if you get detailed errors in the tool.

Comment: Your CPU is reporting an uncorrectable error. Unfortunately, the event log entries are missing crucial information. Please provide information about your hardware. Don’t use DxDiag to do so, just provide the make and model of your system’s components.

Comment: My components are : Motherboard :Asus m5a78lm/usb3,CPU: amd fx  8350 , graphics card :amd Radeon r9 280x

Comment: have you checked for a BIOS update?

Comment: Already running the latest version of BIOS.

Comment: analyze the file 020918-33906-01.dmp in windbg and use [!errrec](https://superuser.com/a/1163779/174557) command to see the cause.

Comment: pastebin of !errorc output https://pastebin.com/BjuUTChx

Comment: [several years ago](https://davidcmoisan.wordpress.com/2010/07/01/bad-hardware-day-more-on-hardware-bluescreens/) a user with this **BUSLG_OBS_ERR_*_NOTIMEOUT_ERR** error had damaged motherboard.

Comment: Do I need another motherboard ?

Comment: do you have a friend with a compatible board for testings?

Comment: wired that fast startup caused 0x124 issues. but nice to see it works for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this (same issue):
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-hardware/fatal-system-crash-wheauncorrectableerror/14fc2f81-fa32-4a3c-9e8b-a9890cc1982d

Try to disable fast startup in power options of control panel. Then proceed shutdown and start again to apply and test new settings.

https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-turn-off-fast-startup-windows-10-a.html

Comment: Worked like a charm !