# Windows 10 crashes after enabling tpm 2.0

Tags: windows, windows-10, updates, tpm

**MY PC AND WHAT I WAS TRYING TO DO**

I wanted to update from win 10 to win 11, and I read that, to do it, I had to enable tpm 2.0. The pc is a custom build and I have a meg z590 ace motherboard. Windows 10 is installed on an SSD.

**PROBLEMS**

So I open the bios and enable tpm 2.0. After enabling it, windows crashes after like 10 seconds I log in my user profile: I get blue screens error “WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR” or the “WATCHDOG_CLOCK_TIMEOUT” one.

I tried to reset the BIOS to factory settings, but I keep getting the errors.

The only option that seems to solve this is to “ripristinate windows”, but by doing that I loose all applications installed, and I prefer to avoid it.

**QUESTION 1**

Is there a way to fix this? Windows should technically be still win 10 since I wasn’t able to update it because of the problem.

- Note: I’m not very familiar with custom builds and a friend of mine helped me and installed for me windows 10 on the USB key.

Comment: Try updating the BIOS and any other drivers you can (Power Driver should be updated).  It is something in your machine (I have not been able to pinpoint), but TPM V2 works fine without crashing on my own machines.

Comment: "Windows 10 is installed on an USB key." - Are you positive that would suggest you are running a Windows to Go installation, which can't be upgraded, I have my doubts the problem is connected to enabling fTPM from within the firmware because if it was caused by that action disabling it would resolve the problem.

Comment: We can't really help unless you provide the Bugcheck Analysis which is generated by Windbg.exe[.](https://superuser.com/questions/1162992/whea-uncorrectable-error-what-now) Of course I understand that is difficult without a machine that can run that tool.

Comment: @Ramhound I didn’t know what you are talking about, so I’ll try and ask my friend that took care of the installation. Anyway, why should the upgrade of windows be a problem related to my problems? I wasn’t able to update it: just after enabling the tpm 2.0 the problems arrived.

Comment: @Ramhound thanks anyway, I’ll try to do as you explained.

Comment: @selenio34 - "why should the upgrade of windows be a problem related to my problems?" - Because it's a relative fact to understanding your current problem.  It makes a big difference if you were booting to a Windows to Go installation.

Comment: @Ramhound ah ok, so if I understood correctly, you think that the problems are not really related to enabling tpm 2.0 itself, but to enabling it on a windows to go installation? Anyway, I’ll update the question and the comments as soon as I know if it really is a windows to go installation or not

Comment: @Ramhound I updated the question: I thought that windows was on the USB key, but it was only installed with it (so windows is actually on my SSD). Sorry for the confusion. Do you have other suggestions, since the “it’s a windows to go problem” it’s not a possibility anymore? Thanks in advance

Comment: these errors are usually hardware related, especially cpu overclock and memory. If your bios has an "auto cpu boost" or other overclock setting, try turning it off or less aggressive. If you have discreet GPU, try disabling the CPU-integrated graphics. etc.

Comment: Ok thanks @Yorik, but I do not have overclocked my PC, and I used it for very little time and for not too cpu-heavy stuff. I will check for the auto cpu boost setting.